# css align table

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

i'm new to html and i'm having problems moving the table down the page. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=eqdpjb&s=7 . I tried setting the 'margin-top: 400;' which works however the navigation bar at the top (i created in dreamweaver using the navigation 'wizard') moves as well to the bottom of the page!. How can i fix this? i want to move only the table without affecting the navigation bar been driving me nuts!

css

```
table{
    background: whitesmoke;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding `margin-top: 400px;` to `table` and it also moves the navigation, then that either means the navigation is also a `table` or the navigation is within the `table`.

If the navigation is also a `table` you will have to give the bottom table a unique `id` and then add the `margin` to that `id` only.

If the navigation is within the `table`, put it in its own div.

If it's none of the above you will have to post some HTML.

Comment: Change `<table>` to `<table id="content">`, then `#content { margin-top: 400px; }`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your navigation is positioned relatively to your table so when you add a margin also the navigation gets the margin.

The solution would be to add a minus margin to your navigation, as shown here:

```
#navigationId {
    margin-top: -400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 table {
 background: whitesmoke;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 margin-right: auto;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 margin-left: auto;
 }
```

Hope it works for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Longer term, I advise you to learn to hand code using an ide such as netbeans or a simple editor such as notepad++. Using dreamweaver is all very well but unless you understand how the code works you will always encounter similar frustrations. A great resource to learn html and css is w3schools www.w3schools.com

A very good book on css is css the missing manual (o'reilly)

You may find all this slower in the beginning but you will end up writing cleaner and faster code as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the table and the navigation bar are in two separate     tags, which are both in a third div.

By using margin-top on the div with the table, you will force that entire div down from the top of that third container div.
Make sure to get rid of the margin-top stuff in the table css declaration.

Eg.
    
    
    Navigation code here.
    
    
    Table here